# Strings Content is actually Bytes

Tags: python

I got a string (return value from website) `encryptedText="b'gAAAAABhdoRSo3k8NAXitaA=='"`, which is actually just bytes.

How do I tell Python, that this is bytes and not a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primarily, by fixing the process that ended up with you having a the repr of a bytestring in a text string. That code is broken, and you shouldn't try to "fix it in post".

However, in this case you can just use `ast.literal_eval()` (since you clearly have a `repr` of a `bytes` in the variable):

```
>>> import ast, base64
>>> encryptedText="b'gAAAAABhdoRSo3k8NAXitaA=='"
>>> t = ast.literal_eval(encryptedText)
b'gAAAAABhdoRSo3k8NAXitaA=='
>>> type(t)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> base64.b64decode(t)
b'\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00av\x84R\xa3y<4\x05\xe2\xb5\xa0'
```

Comment: Thank you! I now came up with a (maybe?) better solution:
The return value from the website is now a hex, wich I then convert back to bytes.

Comment: That still sounds like an extra step. Could you maybe add the value-getting code to your original question?

Comment: The whole thing is a flask app and I get the encrypted text from an input field (encryptedText = request.form['text']). So there isn't really a way around the string.

Comment: If that truly is all you have to get `encryptedText`, then something must be posting that data in the "broken" format...

Answer (score 0):

you received a string, so you basically will have to encode it to bytes again:

```
bytes(a[1:-1],'utf-8')
```

and then decode. In one line:

```
bytes(a[1:-1],'utf-8').decode("utf-8")
```